# Timestamp response behaviors in different tools

Tags: timestamp, icmp, fingerprint

I was testing out icmp time stamp response on one of my servers using `ping` and `hping3`.

Here is result of `hping3`

```
# hping3 --icmp-ts x.x.x.x
HPING  x.x.x.x: icmp mode set, 28 headers + 0 data bytes
len=40 ip=x.x.x.x ttl=56 id=45158 icmp_seq=0 rtt=7.2 ms
ICMP timestamp: Originate=41509629 Receive=12709214 Transmit=12709214
ICMP timestamp RTT tsrtt=7

len=40 ip=x.x.x.x ttl=56 id=45159 icmp_seq=1 rtt=6.6 ms
ICMP timestamp: Originate=41510629 Receive=12710214 Transmit=12710214
ICMP timestamp RTT tsrtt=6
```

and results from `ping` with the -T tsandaddr option:

```
# ping -T tsandaddr x.x.x.x
PING  (x.x.x.x) 56(124) bytes of data.
```

It doesn't return any results.

May I know which is more accurate? `hping3` manage to receive a response. Also, when doing a normal `ping` to my server, the behavior is Port unreachable :

```
# ping x.x.x.x
PING x.x.x.x 56(84) bytes of data.
From x.x.x.x icmp_seq=1 Destination Port Unreachable
...
```

since it's unreachable, why did `hping3` receive a response? Or am i interpreting the output of `hping3` wrongly?

I am doing this test on linux
thanks

Comment: This is in no way an InfoSec question.

Comment: If you want to understand what may be different, capture the packets from your machine when you run the 2 tests and see how the 2 programs send their traffic.

Comment: Thanks but why not? this is under pen testing topic which is also infosec

Comment: Nothing about your tests have anything to do with pentesting. This is a networking question that might be useful when pentesting.